# Hiding jQueryUI tooltip when clicking on target="_blank" link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm using jQuery to show tooltips on every  link on my page that has a 'details' attribute

```
        $(function() {
            $tooltip = $(document).tooltip({
                show: false,
                track: true,
                items: "a[data-details]",
                content: function() {
                    return $( this ).data('details');
                }
            });
        });
```

This works very well. However, when the user clicks one of those links, the URL is opened in a new tab (using target="_blank"). The problem is that the tooltip is still open when the user gets back on the first tab.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
$('a[data-details]').on('click mousedown mouseup', function() { // this might be overkill
    $(document).tooltip("close");                               // Doesn't work at all
    $('div[class^="ui-tooltip"]').remove();                     // removes the tooltip onclick, but gets it back opened when returning on the tab
});
```

Is there a way to keep the tooltips closed when the new page is opened?

Thank you for your help.

Here's a fiddle illustrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/su4v757a/

Note: I'm using jQuery 1.12.4 with jQueryUI 1.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is probably a bug.

As far as I can tell this must be a bug.
 And you could let them know over at https://bugs.jqueryui.com/report/10?P=tooltip

I notice that the `.tooltip("close")` doesn't work in the fiddle. However the tooltip listens to the "mouseleave"-event to close, and we can force that by `$('a[data-details]').trigger("mouseleave");`

If you try this out you will see that it do close, but pops up again:

```
$('a[data-details]').on('click mousedown mouseup', function() { // this might be overkill
    $(this).trigger("mouseleave");
  });
```

Hover and click the "me":

[image: Hover and click the "me"]

Coming back to the page notice that the tooltip has closed and come back again:
[image]

### Workaround - possible solution

Since `.hide()`-ing an element triggers the "mouseleave"-event you could do something funky like hiding the link on click, and showing it just a moment later.

```
  $('a[data-details]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide(); 
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.show()
    }, 1);
  });
```

Setting the timeout to 1 ms would not create any flickering of the link, making the hide/show unnoticeable for the user.

Works in Chrome. Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/cyx6528e/1/
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Unfortunately, the workaround doesn't work in Firefox. I will let them know about this bug

Comment: In Firefox you can see that the link is still in focus / selected. This might be the actual issue. If you simply ``$(this).blur()`` on click, it will "unfocus" the link and the tooltip closes. Updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cyx6528e/2/

Answer (score 0):

tooltip usually works on hover functionality, can you provide js fiddle for your problem

Comment: Added a jsfiddle. Hovering works fine. The problem is that when you click on the link, and then come back on the previous tab, the tooltip is still displayed even though the link isn't hovered anymore